# Unit testing WPF FrameworkElement loading problems

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I am trying to make unit tests for a WPF application via rendering the window in the test thread and examining components to make sure everything's there and working. I am able to get the window to load on an STA thread and show the content correctly on visual inspection, but the main window loads in a custom panel, and that panel's FrameworkElement.Loaded event does not fire as it should when I call Show and Activate, but it does fire in the main code. I have tried this on MSTest, Xunit, and Nunit. From looking around I'm assuming the issue is some part of WPF that is not being set up in test threads, but I don't know which, not familiar enough with the workings of WPF. What do I need to add to make it so my tests properly fire the Loaded event, and how can I do that in the unit test format(s)?

Comment: First of all, I am impressed that you manage to do that and even make some progress, but I would recommend you to think about ROI in writing this kind of test. Is it really worthy writing such a fancy code to unit test if a component is there? or is it more important to test the business logic flow and data change correctly reflected on the view models? Your loaded event could just fire a command or event, and then it will trigger some data changed, all you need is to test the properties are updated. On unit-level, we may want to separate the UI components, just MHO

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of test. What you want is a coded UI test. Unit test are just not built for that what you are doing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: Coded UI tests/Appium don't work for what I'm trying to do, I can't do what I need to without isolating chunks of the interface, actually allowing the code to follow through would be...problematic. UI automation has been quite sufficient for operating the interface so far, I just need to get events like Loaded to work.